# Create an HTML table with fixed left and right column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

In a pickle at the moment. I built a booking system for a client of mine with no chance of going responsive any time soon. That any time soon came last week. I thought I built my code in a way that it's responsive ready. What I want to achieve in mobile/table is to have the very left and very right columns to stay fixed and all the columns in between to scroll/swipe.
I have a dev link up you can view:

[example](http://www.ccy.com.au/availability_Dev/)

You can see from the example the very left column is info about the booking and the very right is the proceed button. Those are the columns that have to stay fixed. Is there a way to achieve this with CSS only? I have a lot of javascript code running as it is and I want to explore all options before resorting to it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
I have so far added a set width to the first and last column using

```
td:first-child
td:last-child{
    width:120px;
}
```

Which is a great start. but the columns in between the first and last get squishy in responsive which is not good usability/readability. I'd like to achieve some sort of horizontal overflow to allow the user to scroll/swipe on mobile/tablet

Comment: Use the `min-width` css property for the columns in the header row.

Comment: @Kami I have applied a set width for the first and last column now. But the columns in between are now squished together which is not good usability/readability. I want some horizontal overflow to allow the user to scroll/swipe through the dates for any particular row

Comment: It is not possible directly with CSS to fix two columns while scrolling the rest.  You may be able to achieve the effect with a table embedded in the centre that scrolls horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

add to the first and last column a class with fixed width 
or min-width (if it can be greater but not less then the specified value)

Comment: If you look at the example and do a hard refresh (shift + f5) to grab the new CSS you can see the columns in between all squished up which isn't good usability/readability! Good start though!

Comment: you can also add a min-witdh to the columns in between, so that these aren't squished and always readable to a certain point

Comment: Yes I did do that using nth-child. I set a min width and while it does work, it only works until the screen width is about 700px. By then the table busts out and you can only see half of the table.